# Regularity of $k[X,Y,Z]/(Z^2 - f(X)g(Y))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $R = k[X,Y,Z]/(Z^2 - f(X)g(Y))$, for an algebraically closed field $k$ with $\operatorname{char} k\not=2$, and $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ have only simple roots in $k$. Determine the maximal ideals $M$ such that $R_M$ are regular local rings.

**EDIT** - based on very helpful hint by @Youngsu. A different answer without the Jacobian criterion by @user26857 can be found below.

There are two types of maximal ideals in $R$: $M = (X-\alpha,Y-\beta,Z)$ when $\alpha$ is a root of $f(X)$ or $\beta$ is a root of $g(Y)$, and $M=(X-\alpha,Y-\beta,Z-\sqrt{f(X)g(Y)})$ when neither $\alpha$ nor $\beta$ are roots.

Now, applying the Jacobian criterion, one must find when $$\operatorname{rank}(\frac{\partial(Z^2 - f(X)g(Y))}{\partial X} \bmod{M},\frac{\partial(Z^2 - f(X)g(Y))}{\partial Y} \bmod{M},\frac{\partial(Z^2 - f(X)g(Y))}{\partial Z} \bmod{M}) = 3 - \dim(R_M) = 1.$$

By differentiating and taking into account that only simple roots exist for $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ one finds that only when both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ respectively the localization at $M = (X-\alpha,Y-\beta,Z)$ is not regular.

Does this work? Or have I misunderstood something? There is one detail missing also - the Jacobian criterion works if $(Z^2 - f(X)g(Y))$ is radical, right? How could I prove this?

Comment: Did you check what happens if you apply the Jacobian criterion? Your maximal ideal should not contain it to be regular.

Comment: If $f=X(X-1)$, $g=Y-1$ and $\alpha=\beta=0$, then $m=(X,Y,Z)$, and the localization is regular since $Z^2-X(X-1)(Y-1)\notin m^2$.

Comment: Your argument looks okay to me. (You actually edited the question a little, so now it's also okay.)

Comment: @user26857 excellent. I edited the question once again as to avoid confusion, if anyone should find this useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to figure out when $Z^2-f(X)g(Y)\in\mathfrak m-\mathfrak m^2$.
It's obvious that $Z^2-f(X)g(Y)\in\mathfrak m$.
[Taylor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions) shows that $Z^2-f(X)g(Y)\in\mathfrak m^2$ iff its first partial derivatives are zero in $(\alpha,\beta,\sqrt{ f(\alpha)g(\beta)})$, that is, $f'(\alpha)g(\beta)=0$, $f(\alpha)g'(\beta)=0$, $f(\alpha)g(\beta)=0$.

Comment: I can't really use Taylor's theorem as it wasn't covered in our class. As I am looking for a method here, more than a solution, is there a different approach?

Comment: @baltazar As far as I know, if $(R,m)$ is local regular, and $x\in m$, then $R/(x)$ is regular iff $x\notin m^2$. Now, if $m=(X-a,Y-b,Z-c)$, then a polynomial $f(X,Y,Z)\in m$ is in $m^2$ iff... (I leave you this part to find out an alternative approach, if there is one).

Comment: Where can I find a proof of this statement - "$(R,m)$ is local regular, and $x \in m$, then $R/(x)$ is regular iff $x \not\in m^2$"? I am just starting out with regularity, so I don't have my basics covered yet.

Comment: A statement from undergrad calculus can't be used in graduate(ish) algebra? This seems odd.

Comment: Taylor's theorem in algebra is more or less a change of variables: $X -\alpha$ and $Y -\beta$ are just as good as $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @baltazar First of all let me make a small correction: $x$ has to be supposed a non-zerodivisor (or $\ne 0$ if one knows that local rings are integral domains). The key steps for proving the claim are the following: if $x\in m-m^2$ then $\operatorname{edim}R/(x)=\operatorname{edim}R-1$, while for $x\in m^2$ we have $\operatorname{edim}R/(x)=\operatorname{edim}R$, and for a non-zerodivisor $\dim R/(x)=\dim R-1$. (Here $\operatorname{edim}R:=\dim_{R/m}m/m^2$.) Knowing this the claim is obvious.