# What can be said about a regular quotient (by a principal prime ideal) of a polynomial ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be irreducible (so (f) is a prime ideal).
Assume $S:=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(f)$ is regular, where, by definition, a noetherian ring is regular is all its localizations at maximal ideals are regular local rings.

My questions:

(1) What can be said about $S$? 
I am especially interested to know if such $S$ must be a UFD?
Notice that we know that $S$ is normal, since every regular ring is normal.
($S \cong \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}]$? maybe this is too much to ask).

(2) What can be said about $f$? For example: monic? of degree? not in any $m^2$ ($m$ maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$). Something about its partial derivatives?

-Remark: "Cohen-Macaulay rings" by Bruns and Herzog, Proposition 2.2.4 deals with the local case, namely: "If $A$ is a regular local ring and $I$ an ideal of $A$, then: $A/I$ is regular iff $I$ is generated by a subset of a regular system of parameters".
How can I apply this to my questions?

Any help will be appreciated. (Sorry if my questions are trivial; I am only beginning to study this topic).

Edit: I have already asked a similar question:
[Regularity of a quotient ring of the polynomial ring in three indeterminates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287044/regularity-of-a-quotient-ring-of-the-polynomial-ring-in-three-indeterminates)

I posted the current question to MO, since I expected to get more answers there... I must confess I am disappointed.
The solution with partial derivatives I already knew (one direction can be found in the above link), sorry I did not mention it before. However, I expected to get other ideas in MO.

Comment: Yes, something about the partial derivatives: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_an_algebraic_variety

Comment: Thank you! It would be great, if and when you have time, to explain a little what is exactly the claim I can apply.

Comment: Certainly $S$ need not be a UFD.  You might want to consider the case when $n$ equals $2$ and $f$ equals $x_2^2 -x_1(x_1-1)(x_1-\lambda)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Nice! Truly, I am interested in $n=3$, so can your counterexample be adjusted to it (actually, I have some additional restrictions on $f$).

Comment: $f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ is of the following form: $a_nz^n+\ldots+a_1z+a_0$, $a_n,\ldots,a_1,a_0 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, with $n \geq 2$. (Namely, at least one of the three indeterminates has degree $\geq 2$).

Comment: There is not much you can say because for random choices of the coefficients, the variety is regular with probability 1. So you can't say anything that is true for a polynomial that isn't very special. What you can say about the partial derivatives is that they don't all vanish, together with the function itself, at a point - otherwise the local ring is not regular. This should be in any introductory text on commutative algebra.

Comment: @WillSawin: Please, can you explain "...because for random choices of the coefficients, the variety is regular with probability 1". How have you obtained that conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $S$ is a complete intersection, but no need to be a UFD. A classical example of non-UFD is $\mathbb C[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$.
2. $f$ is certainly not in $m^2$ for any maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Since $m=(x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n)$ we have $f\in m-m^2$ iff $f(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a_1,\dots,a_n)\ne0$ for some $i$.

Comment: Thanks! (again). Is there an example of a regular non-UFD $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(f)$, with $f$ having at least one of $x,y,z$ of degree $\geq 2$?

Comment: @user237522 Yes, it is: $\mathbb C[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$.

Comment: Nice! Actually, in the case I have in mind $a_nz^n+\ldots+a_1z+a_0$,  $n \geq 2$ and I do not allow $a_n \in \mathbb{C}$. But of course I do not expect you to guess this; I should have written this explicitly.

Comment: @user237522 I'm afraid I don't get your last comment: that polynomial is $f$? If yes, then where are the variables $x,y$?

Comment: Yes, $f=a_nz^n+\ldots+a_1z+a_0$, where $a_n,\ldots,a_1,a_0 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, $n \geq 2$. And I demand that $a_n \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]-\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The example (1) in the answer is not regular. It is singular at the origin. For any `general' polynomial of degree 3 (and in particular you can arrange the top degree term in $z$ is $xz^2$)  in $x,y,z$ will be a non-UFD. For example, if I have done my calculations right) $xy^2+z^2y+(z+x^2)$ will be one such.

Comment: @Mohan You could post an answer dealing with the degree 3 case.

Comment: @Mohan: Thanks! But in your example $f=xy^2+z^2y+z+x^2$, it seems that $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(f)$ is not regular...For example, take $(i,-1,1+i)$ and get $f(i,-1,1+i)=0$ and all partial derivatives of $f$ at this point also vanish. Am I missing something?

Comment: The partial derivative with respect to $x$ is $y^2+2x$ and it does not vanish at your point.

Comment: You are right...sorry for the comment. I wonder how you found such $f$? (maybe: experience +intuition+ luck).

Answer (score 1):

Just to fill in, if you look at the projective surface $xy^2+z^2y+zt^2+x^2t=0$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$, it is smooth and then it is well known (look at any algebraic geometry text book about smooth cubic surfaces) that the class group is a free abelian group of rank 7. $t=0$ has only three curves and thus the complement $t=1$ has class group rank at least 4, hence not a UFD, which is my example above. With a bit of calculation, you can also check that the ideal $(x,z)$ is a prime ideal of height one which is not principal.

Comment: Thanks!. Sorry for the probably trivial question, but how do you know that $xy^2+z^2y+z+x^2$ is irreducible?

Comment: Is it follows from (simple) considerations of degrees? namely writing $f$ as a product of two polynomials (each of total degree at most $3$), and getting a trivial factorization.